# Printing on console WIN32/WTL

Tags: winapi, console, printing, wtl

I am developing WTL GUI application.
I want to print something on console.
How to enable console printing in win32/WTL application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx) to attach to a new console.  (This will fail if your program is being run from a console window in the first place, but that's ok.)  Also look at [this page](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm) for a fully worked example.

Comment: I think you should have added the gist from that link. It's crucial to link the new console window to the C runtime handles for `stdout` and `stderr`.